# JavaScript: How do I get to disable a button based on a list data?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I am new to JavaScript...I have a page users use to register for training classes. Once they view a class, if they are interested in registering, all they need to do is click on a "Register" button to get registered for the course. I want to make changes to this JavaScript code to disable the button, if the maximum amount of available seats for the course is reached. So on the list, there is a field that states the maximum number of seats available and another field that shows how many people are enrolled so far. Once the max number is reached, I want to disable to "Register" button. Here is what the current code looks like...

```
<span id="ms-rterangecursor-start"></span><span id="ms-rterangecursor-end">                </span></style><script type="text/javascript">
 function openDialog(pUrl, requestType) 
 {  
   SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(   
     {  
       url: pUrl,
       width: 650,  
       height: 550,  
       title: requestType  


      }    
   )
 }
```

https://myserver/sp/mysite/Lists/Class%20Roster/NewForm.aspx','Sign up for this Training Class')">Sign up for this Training Class

How do I get this done? I appreciate the help and ideas.

Comment: How do you update the number of people already registered? Is it just when page loads or is it real time??

Comment: Is this standard DOM manipulation or is sharepoint different/unique?